# my print("Found faces", str(len(faces))) not executed

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to detect multiple faces using opencv in python. I'm doing this in raspbian OS (raspberry Pi 3). Although the code is working properly, i.e, it's detecting a face and drawing a rectangular boundary around the face. It successfully saves the image in my local folder as well. The problem is : the statement print("Found faces", str(len(faces))) isn't working and the console remains blank. What am I missing here or where am I going wrong?

```
import io
import picamera
import cv2
import numpy
stream = io.BytesIO()

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (320, 240)
    camera.hflip = True
    camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg')


buff = numpy.fromstring(stream.getvalue(), dtype=numpy.uint8)

image = cv2.imdecode(buff, 1)

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('face1.xml')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 5)

print("Found faces", str(len(faces)))

for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,0),2)

cv2.imwrite('result.jpg',image)
```

Comment: If the lines after the `print()` call have the effect you were looking for, then your stdout is not connected to your console; the print output is going somewhere else perhaps?

Comment: well if that is so, then what do you think I should do to make it work?

Comment: I don't know, I don't know how you execute the script. It's not a Python problem, at any rate.

Comment: Nor an opencv problem...